# SE needs special event chat rooms

Tags: feature-request, chat

Here I am on a Thanksgiving night looking for a turkey wizard to give me proper instruction on how to remove or mitogate that unpleasant gamey turkey flavour. To my suprise, on a such a ceremonious day in a foreign land, there's no way for me to obtain this information in realtime such as a chat group.  Thus, I am forced to rely on my naive improvisations and intuition, hoping my efforts will not result in embarrassment in front of my honoured American guests. An ephemeral chat group, if only for a day, would be greatly welcomed.

Comment: I don't understand what you need extra beyond what is already possible on Chat.se? Anyone with 100 rep can create a chatroom and once set you can advertise it a bit, either in existing chatrooms or by adding an chatevent for the room itself.

Comment: As I mentioned in another comment, an official chatroom with an announcement will get more participation, better serve new users and adds additional value to SE sites,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## What are my ideas for this?

I think this could possibly be a good idea, but only for **some** sites.

## What would it possibly look like?

For example, in Seasoned Advice when it is a special holiday that is somewhat related to cooking, like Thanksgiving, there could be a special chat room which you can ask questions about cooking Thanksgiving foods, after a while, it would get a quick and simple answer.

After the holiday had passed, the chat room would be disabled until the holiday returns back again.

### What if there are issues?

I don't think there would be any issues with this, except for some duplicate questions and some off-topic discussions.

### But wait, you can just ask a question on the site itself.

Well, I can disagree with that a bit, asking a question can take some time until someone answers it, and it might not even be correct. With these, it might only take a little while until someone answers because there would be active users in the chat room always answering questions.

## Will these chat rooms possibly be for all sites?

Again, if this is implemented most sites might not have these chat rooms, like Stack Exchange, because there is no holiday related to coding, from what I know. (Unless there is some secret coding holiday out there, who knows.)

Comment: I am not sure why my question was closed. I am not sure what's unclear about it. I was suggesting a special event chat room. This would also be cool for special events like Apple Keynotes or election nights,

Comment: I don't understand why you say *there could be a special chat room*. With 100 rep  anyone can create a chatroom. There is no *could*, what the OP wants is already possible.

Comment: Yes, but it is not an official chatroom that's advertised to the site's visitors. A thanksgiving chatroom for cooking.se to share tips, a chatroom for WWDC on askdifferent.se, a chartroom for solar eclipses or SpaceX launch on astronomy.se. Such chatroo,s add value to SE's offerings.